# Send value checkbox in mail

Tags: checkbox

i have a problem with send value multi checkbox by mail:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="wiztype[]" value="value1">
<input type="checkbox" name="wiztype[]" value="value2">
<input type="checkbox" name="wiztype[]" value="value3">
<input type="checkbox" name="wiztype[]" value="value4">
<input type="checkbox" name="wiztype[]" value="value5">
```

I'm trying to use the plugin for validating form, i have there:

```
var wiztype = $("input[name='wiztype[]']:checked").serializeArray();
```

In the mail-proces.php i have:

```
$wiztype = $_POST["wiztype"];
```

In the mail I have:

```
 [object Object],[object Object] (x number of selected boxes)
```

I tried to do foreach

```
if(!empty($_POST['wiztype'])) {
foreach($_POST['wiztype'] as $wiztypelist) {
        $wiztypelist;
}
}
```

What can i do with this? Please help :)

Comment: _What can i do with this?_ Be more specific... It is unclear what you are trying to ask

Comment: Excuseme, i thout it's clear. It doesn't work. Values from checkbox do not pass.